# Yii: Generating PDF document from server response by streaming HTML into PDF

Tags: yii, pdf-generation

I am new to web development and remember from past that a friend of mine once had an implementation in which Server response stream of HTML was stored in a variable and then output as PDF, this was JSP some ages ago. I don't know how to achieve this in Yii rather bit skeptical if I even remember it right. I have explored TCPDF and can produce the PDF by coding the HTML tags, however, I am looking into the option to stream the output of a URL response in a variable and then use that to generate the PDF. I did the following but it is not working. I receive error at **filesize($filename)**:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$filename = 'http://localhost/webapp/index.php/link/to/some/page';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$pdf->writeHTML($contents ,true);
```

I am bit lost on how to achieve this, all the help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get the content of a webpage you could achieve that by rendering the page into the controller and assign it to a variable which you can then store in the PDF file

Comment: ThomasVdBerge. I got the detailed solution on the same lines what you described. I have added answer to this, please see for details. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with help from other [forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37202-yii-generating-pdf-document-from-server-response-by-streaming-html-into-pdf/page__gopid__179498#entry179498). I hope it help those who may wish to achieve the same. The solution is to use [Yii-pdf](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf). I have successfully tested it with html2pdf and it works like a charm.